# Scatter does not cycle through Cycler

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to be able to use the Cycler method of matplotlib using a scatter plot. However, it seems the scatter method does not cycle whereas e.g. the plot method does. See MWE below

```
import numpy as np
from cycler import cycler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.rand(5,10)
y = np.random.rand(5,10)

color = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1,x.shape[0]))
custom_cycler = (cycler(color=color) *
  cycler(marker=['o', 's']))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)
ax.scatter(x,y)
fig,ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(x,y)
```

the scatter does not change color whereas the plot does

[image: scatter]
[image: plot]

Apparently this has been [discussed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3041) but I dont' get what I am supposed to do to achieve what I desire in a scatter i.e. being able to cycle both on the marker and the color using the elegant cycler methodology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separately create the cycler for the color and the marker as partly suggested in the link you provided.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(123)
import itertools
from cycler import cycler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(5,10)
y = np.random.rand(5,10)

color = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1,x.shape[0]))
custom_cycler = (cycler(color=color))
marker = itertools.cycle(('o', 's')) 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    ax.plot(i, j, linestyle='', marker=next(marker) )
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so the easiest way is to move from scatter to plot and use an empty linestyle. With this, you don't even need to use next(marker) you can directly make a custom_cycler that cycles both on color & marker

Comment: @FenryrMKIII: Yes, that might work too, as long as the job gets done

Comment: @FenryrMKIII: If you use your definition of `custom_cycler`, you don't get all the colors of the viridis color map

Comment: Yes it depends on what you want to cycle first - marker or colors I guess